# Can I retrieve the 'check ins' I have made on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I would like to get the lats and lons of all the check ins I have done via teh Facebook 'check in' button. Is there an API call I can make?

Foursquare let's you do this, can't see any reference on FB.

Answer (score 0):

Checkins can be retrieved via [`checkins`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#checkins) connection of [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object, you also need `user_checkins` permission (or `friends_checkins` if you retrieving friend's checkins).

Also you habe ability to access same data via FQL:

```
SELECT coords, tagged_uids, page_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid=me()
```

You probably want also to read [documentation of `checkin` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) and [documentation for `checkin` table (FQL)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/)

Comment: Hi all. Yes got that working using FQL, tested throught their explorer:

SELECT coords, author_uid, tagged_uids, page_id, timestamp, message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid= me()

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20coords%2C%20author_uid%2C%20tagged_uids%2C%20page_id%2C%20timestamp%2C%20message%20FROM%20checkin%20WHERE%20author_uid%3D%20me%28%29

Thanks so much for the help, Alex

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

The Place field returns an

> object containing the Page id, name, and location; location includes
>   the specific latitude and longitude along with information about the
>   postal addresses, if available

You can also use:

> Checkins: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin (This request
>   returns you or your friend's latest checkins, or checkins where you or
>   your friends have been tagged; currently, it does not accept a q=
>   parameter.)

I think the second is more what you are looking for.

A third approach is to use FQL:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/

Comment: Seems like you misinterpreting OP's question, he want to access his own checkins via API.

Comment: Thanks for this - this only seems to return what is available very recently, hoping for my check ins of all-time. Any thoughts?